# How to convert any XML code into JSON

Tags: json, xml

I have written code in **XML** and want convert it to **JSON**.

Example:

```
// xml code :  xmlstr += "<" + idname + ">" + value + "</" + idname + ">";

// xml code:  xmlstr += "<" + idname + ">false</" + idname + ">";
```

Please assist me.

Comment: Firstly, string concatenation is a lousy way of generating XML. This is why there's so much bad XML in the world - people don't even bother to try and escape special characters. Use a library. Secondly, if you used a library then it would be much easier to produce an alternate library with the same interface that emitted JSON instead of XML.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the programming environment you are working in, there is likely to be a library that does this for you.

For example:

- in JavaScript there is [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js).
- in Python there is [xml2json](https://github.com/hay/xml2json).
- in Java there is [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java).
- etc.

I would recommend this approach since a popular library is likely to be well tested and handle edge-cases that it would otherwise take you a while to ferret out.

Answer (score 0):

[XML to JSON Converter](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html)

> This online tool allows you to convert an XML file into a JSON file.
>   This process is not 100% accurate in that XML uses different item
>   types that do not have an equivalent JSON representation.